# To Add if else statement into While loop VHDL

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I am trying to work on inserting if else to loop but it is still expecting some syntax. I cant figure out why this if/else statement wont compile. I am new to VHDL, please help. This is one of the steps along the way and i am stuck.

```
variable i : integer := 0;
    begin
        
        while i < 10 loop
            report "i=" & integer'image(i);
            i := i + 1;

    if i = 6 then
    report "okay good job";
    else i = 5 then
    report " okay nice work";
    else 
    report " not equal to 5 and 6";

        end loop;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-1993 8. Sequential Statements, [8.7 If statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ETd5.jpg). in the BNF square brackets indicate optional items. sequence_of_statements ::= { sequential_statement }, where curly brackets indicate zero or more repetitions. Boldface denotes reserved words.

Answer (score 2):

In VHDL, the keywords are if, elsif and else

```vhdl
if condition_1 then
  -- do something
elsif condition_2 then
  -- do something else
else
  -- do something when all other conditions are false
end if;
```